# MPAndroid chart hide labels from X axis and show on double tap

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, axis-labels, bubble-chart

I ma using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) bubble chart. when I run the app it shows x axis values hidden. like I have x-axis label January, February, march, April, may,june. but when app run it shows January , April
 and June. on double tape on label it zoom the chart and show hidden labels. I want to show all in a sequence so that user troll horizontal and view all. no need to double tap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after expanding MP Android Chart documentation.
you can do so set thee labels to skip 0. It will skip no label from xAxis.

```
XAxis xAxis = bubbleChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0);
```

Comment: I hope you all will find it best.

Answer (score 3):

You can determinate the numbers of labels to display. This prevents them from hiding automatically.

```
XAxis xAxis = bubbleChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setLabelCount(data.length);
```

Comment: i have another problem in MP android bar chart. all bar mess up in one screen. don't scroll horizontal. it creates a bad UI.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why would you do that. The library does a great job in automatically deciding how many labels to show on either X or Y axis to make the chart nice and readable.

If the chart is narrow, it might happen that your values will overlap, that's why the library skips a few, to make the chart look good.

If that still doesn't help, you can play around with the spacings between axis labels - check out the [library's documentation for these specific items](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/AxisBase.java)

Other solution may be to [rotate](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/XAxis.java) the labels of the X axis with the help of

```
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(35);
```

Comment: but I have to show x-axis values in a sequence, so I have to show all

Comment: still having an issue. I want to scroll x-axis labels. but its overlapping as you said when values a re more. what should I do.?

Comment: IMO you should keep the built-in behaviour. If the labels do not fit, why showing all of them? I don't think anyone has a hard time reading a chart which has every second month skipped(in your specific case)...that's how charts work.. If, for some reason you're crazy about having everything displayed, try rotating the labels: xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle()   https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/XAxis.java